# Stored procedure won't run on Ado.Net but in SQL Server (SSMS)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a stored procedure which always runs normally using ADO.Net & `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database` helper.

Recently, I encountered a problem when I had to run this stored procedure with a really huge `string` parameter. The input parameter is of type `nvarchar(max)`.

So I decided to monitor executed statement using SQL Server Profiler. The Profiler shows me that the exact statement that I expected comes from `ADO` and this statement can be easily copied and executed in SSMS with no any trouble.

But it won't run on ADO and surprisingly the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery(...)` is `1`.

One way to go (*MAY BE*) is to write another stored procedure in which there are 4-5 input parameters of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and in C# code, split the main string into these input parameters. etc...

I suspect that SQL Server limits ADO to run this huge stored procedure and  I'm wondering how to know if there is a way/trick/setting/etc... to run the stored procedure "as is" by ADO.
------------------------ Edited ----------------------
As the result, It turns out: I have several problem on my `C#` coding such as *Leave the `Transaction` uncommitted* or *Put the cached data back to the track and ...*.
It's a shame and i'd like to put a sad face here. :-(
But i won't delete the question. Maybe sometimes, someone like me encounter such a problem and jump to the question section instead of take a step back and reevaluate some logic (like transaction and caching) of the code.

Comment: Can you please post your SP? Is it dinamicaly generated?

Comment: I have read somewhere about the limit of parameter from ADO, I will share if I find that. Else you can pass DataTable as parameter... Just a thought

Comment: @C.Helling - I believe the 2100 refers to the number of parameters, not the length of each one.  This case is a weird one, as Profiler actually picked up the whole thing properly.

Comment: @NPras You right. it's a shame but it was caching problem mixing with uncommitted transaction on my c# code. I'm so sorry but a mixture of several problems make me mistake.